# Am I eligible for "Electorate" Badge?

Tags: support, voting, electorate-badge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Electorate badge rules?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34340/electorate-badge-rules)

Here is my profile page [Pandiya Chendur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/146857/pandiya-chendur) on Stack Overflow.

I have `601 upvotes` but I didn't get electorate badge.

How can I see the percentage of my upvotes on questions?  Where can I find this detail?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34340/electorate-badge-rules

Comment: You would have it by now if all those votes were for questions.