# On exactly what criteria is the Electorate badge awarded?

Tags: support, badges, electorate-badge

There is a badge named **Electorate** which is going to be awarded on "Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions". Can somebody explain this to me?

Voted on 600 **Question** and 25% are on **Question**? is this  means

Voted on 600 **Posts** and 25% are on Question

Can't SO place some easy text or Definitions for average users?

Comment: possible duplicate of [List of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) and [Electorate badge rules](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34340/electorate-badge-rules)

Comment: it is not a duplicate one. m not asking for the definition as i can read that from Bedge page on SO, m asking for clarification.

Comment: Have you read the second one I linked to? It's fairly straightforward: 600 votes on questions. At least 25% of all votes on posts are on questions.

Comment: Is there a way to find out how close am I to attain this badge?

Comment: No, i didnt get that. I have 620 votes and still no bedge. Is there any queryr that will tell how far i am ??

Comment: @Sachin & @Hansmukh There's no way of finding out which votes are on questions and which are on answers, so you can't judge your progress towards the badge.

Answer (score 3):

It means you must have at least 600 votes on questions (as opposed to votes on answers) and your amount of votes on questions must be at least 25% of your total amount of votes.

Each time somebody comes and ask for this, the answer he gets is something like "It's quite clear isn't it". While the phrasing is perfectly correct the fact that people keep asking for details might indicate that the badge deserves a verbose explanation.

Comment: @DrDro I don't think you are giving the correct definition. because according to your definition, I must have at least 2400 votes so that 25% of them become 600 which should be cast on questions. see this profile http://stackoverflow.com/users/366495/hal. he has only voted 640 times and he got the `Electorate` badge.

Comment: @Zain: `600/640 = 93.75%`, which is certainly more than the 25% requested. DrDro's definition is clearly saying "*at least* 25%", while you are misreading it as "*at most* 25%".

Comment: @RegDwight than it means, 600/610 = 98.36%. I have voted 610 times. and acc to your calculation it becomes 98.36%, than why did I still not get that badge?

Comment: @Zain: because you have not voted for 600 *questions*. You must have at least 600 votes on questions (as opposed to votes on answers). It's not exactly rocket science.

Comment: @RegDwight okay. It means that the person I mention in my first comment `Hal` might have voted 600 times on questions and only 40 times on answers, right?

Comment: @Zain: precisely. In fact, for all we know, he might have even spent *all* of his votes on questions and never voted for answers at all.

Comment: @RegDwight, hmm, good. than what is 25% here?

Comment: @Zain: the 25% is the minimum threshold for getting the Electorate badge. For example, if you vote on 600 questions after voting on 10,000 answers, you won't get this badge, because `600/10,600 = 5.7%`, and that is smaller than 25%. You have to meet *both* criteria: 1) vote on at least 600 questions *and* 2) vote on at most 3× as many answers.

Comment: @RegDwight, it means that I will have to vote 600 questions and  1800 answers?

Comment: @Zain: it means that when you have voted for exactly 600 questions, you may have voted for *at most* 1800 answers. If you have voted for 1801 answers, you will have to vote for 601 questions. If you have voted for 10,000 answers, you will have to vote for 3,334 questions.

Comment: @RegDwight Then how come `Hal` got `Electorate` badge by total 640 votes?

Comment: @Zain: because he has voted for 600 questions and less than 1800 answers. 40 < 1800.