# Confused about Electorate badge criteria

Tags: support, badges

How can I vote on 600 **questions** but only 25% of them are on **questions**?  Did it originally mean "600 **posts**"?

[image]

Comment: It's 25% of "total votes", not of votes on questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The description is accurate:

- "Vote on 600 questions" -- This means you have to have voted on 600 or more questions.
- "25% or more of total votes are on questions" -- This means that 25% or more of your total votes are on questions.

These two things are not mutually exclusive. Note "total votes" is *total* votes, which is the total of all your votes, not just questions.

If you cast 3000 votes and 600 of those were on questions, you would not qualify, as only 20% of your total votes are on questions. On the other hand if you cast 700 votes and 600 of those were on questions, you would qualify.

You are not the first to be confused by this, however. Related reading:

- [Clarify Electorate badge wording](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34349/clarify-electorate-badge-wording) - This is where the even *more* confusing older wording was changed to its current form.
- [On exactly what criteria is the Electorate badge awarded?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71693/on-exactly-what-criteria-is-the-electorate-badge-awarded) - Clarification of criteria.
- [Suggested minor modification to the Electorate Badge description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175047/suggested-minor-modification-to-the-electorate-badge-description?rq=1) - Suggestions for improvement to current wording.
- Lots of other info here if you search, and similar reports if you look at the related questions list.

Comment: Not to hijack your answer, but maybe you want to extend it a bit further with what happens if (eg) thoe 700 votes go up to (eg) 1200, by voting 500 times and NONE of these 500 ... are on questions. In that case: do you loose the badge again or not? Or do you think that's an interesting question I should post as a followup question to your answer here?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I want to expand on nothing. Also whether you lose it or not is not an interesting question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work

Answer (score 1):

> Vote on 600 questions and **25% or more of total votes are on questions**

Literally! At least 25 percent of your *total votes* were cast on questions. I think you read past the "total votes" part hence the confusion. 25 percent of votes on posts, not just the posts. This is of course a two-piece condition:

- Vote on 600 questions
- 25 percent of all your votes were cast on questions

Twp different conditions, under the same badge. You should consider that in your first question:

> How can I vote on 600 questions but only 25% of them are on questions?

"[T]hem" would represent the *votes you casted*.