# Why don't I have the 'Electorate' badge?

Tags: support, badges, electorate-badge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Electorate badge rules?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34340/electorate-badge-rules)

On StackOverflow, I've got 605 votes, 264 for questions, and 341 for answers.

Doesn't this mean I should have the 'Electorate' badge?

Comment: Why the down-vote? Simple misread, and had my question answered.

Comment: Downvotes here on Meta [mean something different](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) than they do on the main site. Executive summary is not to take them too personally. :-)

Comment: "voting is used to express agreement or disagreement, not to point out a lack of quality or helpfulness" I see :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, here is the badge's description (with my emphasis):

> Voted on 600 **questions** and 25% or more of total votes are on questions

You've only voted on 264 questions, so you fail to meet the highlighted criteria.

A detailed breakdown of your voting history is available in your [user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/370103/curt):

[image: 605 Votes Cast / 264 on questions / 341 on answers]

Comment: duhh sorry! Should've read more carefully.

Comment: Assessing your eligibility for this badge has been made really easy by the way we now break down voting information in the user profile. @Curt Remember that upvotes and downvotes both count, and that downvotes on questions are even free. So feel free to vote down the questions that you think show little research effort, are poorly constructed, or are not a good fit for the site.

Comment: Cheers @Cody Gray